# serializing NLog LogLevel Datatype through a WCF Web Service

Tags: c#, wcf, nlog

I have a wcf WebService with a method which takes [LogLevel](http://nlog-project.org/wiki/Log_Levels) type (part of [Nlog](http://nlog-project.org/)) as a parameter, 
the LogLevel is build in type comes with a framework for logging called [NLog](http://nlog-project.org/), 
Problem is WCF doesnt know how to marshal the loglevel parameter i guess cause its not decorated with DataContract.

is there is any way i can marshal LogLevel through the webservice ?

**Note** im trying not to wrap it in a custom class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't transport the entire LogLevel instance. But you can use the string name instead. Call your method with the property value loglevelInstance.Name and recreate a LogLevel instance at the server side using LogLevel.FromName(theString).

Comment: yeah that what i did i was hoping for any other work arround but i ended up doing that cause i dont have time..

Answer (score 1):

It is could by due to the LogLevel being an enum. Convert it to a text, send it over and then convert it back on the client side.

Comment: It's not an enum, it's a sealed class with "constants" (public readonly fields): [Source on GitHub](https://github.com/jkowalski/NLog/blob/2777b71f19135b9c49cba2b75716c2d9636d5dab/src/NLog/LogLevel.cs)

Comment: Still same solution, send it over as a text and recreate it on the other side.